# How can i search a datagridview using multiple checkboxes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, checkbox, datagridview

This is my first question on this site so i apologise in advance if I format it incorrectly. 
I am creating a system which should be able to search a database (dataGridView) using multiple checkboxes. I found some code online to search it using 3 checkboxes but am unsure how to extend this. I will need to be able to search using 50+ checkboxes. The following code is executed upon pressing of a search button which will display corresponding rows in my database. I want to know to most efficient way to extend this solution to 50+ checkboxes.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String filterdata = "";



        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            if (checkBox2.Checked || checkBox3.Checked)
            {
                filterdata = "'T05A1.1',";

            }
            else
            {
                filterdata = "'T05A1.1'";
            }
        }
        if (checkBox2.Checked)
        {
            if (checkBox3.Checked)
            {
                filterdata = filterdata + "'C16D6.2',";

            }
            else
            {
                filterdata = filterdata + "'C16D6.2'";
            }

        }

        if (checkBox3.Checked)
        {
            filterdata = filterdata + "'F41E7.3'";
        } 


        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        //cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Table1 where elegansgeneID ='" + filterdata + "'";
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Table1 where elegansgeneID in(" + filterdata + ")";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        con.Close(); 

    }
```

Comment: An array of checkboxes, maybe?

Comment: For what do you need 50+ checkboxes? You really should consider other possibilities...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this more shorter approach:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var values = new List<string>();

    if (checkBox1.Checked)
        values.Add("'T05A1.1'");

    if (checkBox2.Checked)
        values.Add("'C16D6.2'");

    if (checkBox3.Checked)
        values.Add("'F41E7.3'");

    // and so on

    String filterdata = string.Join(",", values);

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alexander Petrov's answer is correct.
But if you are getting more than 50 Check boxes then I would suggest you use CheckBoxList. The code becomes more simpler then.

```
  public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<string> filters = new List<string> { "T05A1.1", "C16D6.2", "F41E7.3" };

        checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
        foreach (string filter in filters)
        {
            checkedListBox1.Items.Add(filter);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> selectedFilter = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
        {
            selectedFilter.Add("'" + checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i].ToString() + "'");
        }
        string query = "Select * from Table1 where elegansgeneID in(" + string.Join(",", selectedFilter) + ")";
    }
```

With CheckBoxList, you can just add your filters in the filters List variable and it will generate your list. This will keep your code short as well.